# How do I read until the end of file?

Tags: input, lua, eof

In C, I can read an input and stop the program when it reaches the end of file (`EOF`). Like so.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;       
    while (scanf("%d", &a) != EOF)
        printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do that in Lua?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Lua Documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) features a ton of details on file-reading and other IO. For reading an entire file:

```
t = io.read("*all")
```

apparently reads an entire file. The documentation has examples on reading line-by-line etc. Hope this helps.

**Example on reading all lines of a file and numbering each of them (line-by-line):**

```
   local count = 1
    while true do
      local line = io.read()
      if line == nil then break end
      io.write(string.format("%6d  ", count), line, "\n")
      count = count + 1
    end
```

Comment: Your example program does not line-numbering, but quoted-printable-encoding. (It should better handle the lower control characters to, I think.)

Comment: My bad guys - the wrong example was pasted over :) Both of those are available in the documentation :)

Answer (score 3):

For a similar program in lua, you can read it line by line and check if the line is nil(which is returned when the line is EOF).

```
while true do
  local line = io.read()
  if (line == nil) then break end
end
```

Comment: for s in io.lines() do something end

Comment: @AndresH thanks for the cleaner solution. For some reason I thought it doesn't work with stdin.